# Calculus by Apostol Exercise 1.26 number 26

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image: Problem]
[image: Theorems]

What I did first is to use theorem 1.18 to subtract a from the limits of integration of the integral of f(x), leaving the new limits of integration to be from 0 to (b-a). In that case I can use theorem 1.19 to assume that the k is the (b-a), by algebraic manipulation, I ended up having integral of f[(b-a)a+(b-a)x], which left me stumped, I just can't think of a way to remove that (b-a) beside a. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to apply theorem 1.19 by considering k to be 1/(b-a) and then apply theorem 1.18 for c = - a/(b-a). You'll get what you are looking for !!

I guess you need full workout. Here it is:

For k = 1/(b-a) Theorem 1.19 yields
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = (b-a)\int_{\frac{a}{b-a}}^{\frac{b}{b-a}} f((b-a)x) dx$$

Now theorem 1.18 comes into play. Consider c = - a/(b-a) and apply it to the RHS:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = (b-a)\int_{\frac{a}{b-a}-\frac{a}{b-a}}^{\frac{b}{b-a}-\frac{a}{b-a}} f((b-a)(x+\frac{a}{b-a})) dx \\= (b-a)\int_{0}^{1} f(a+(b-a)x)dx$$ 
Hope it helps.

Comment: The (b-a) will not cancel leaving f[(b-a)^2x+a/(b-a)]...

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Of course, translation applies to the variable x only and not the scaled one i.e. (b-a)x.

Comment: Somehow I know that but can you give a more elaborate explanation on why it just applies only to the variable x and not also on the scaled one?

Comment: Isn't the integration with respect to x?

Comment: Yes, oh, got it. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you are satisfied then please mark the question as answered so that I won't end up here again while looking for unanswered questions. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever applying Theorem 2 you must only take into account the variable of integration ($a$ is fixed):

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_0^{b-a} f(x+a)\, dx = (b-a)\int_0^1 f((b-a)x +a ) \, dx.
$$

To see it more clearly, just take an $x \in [0,1]$. Then, $(b-a)x$ lies in $[0,b-a]$, and $(b-a)x+a$ lies in $[a,b]$, which was the original interval. Or you can also write $f_a(x)=f(x+a)$, so that you have

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{b-a} f(x+a)\, dx &= \int_0^{b-a} f_a(x)\, dx = (b-a)\int_0^1 f_a((b-a)x)\, dx \\
& = (b-a)\int_0^1 f((b-a)x +a ) \, dx.
\end{align*}